# ElasticSearch: Poor search results using "OR" operator

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using a multimatch query in ES with the "OR" operator. The problem I'm running into is that ES doesn't know which term is most important in a search query. When searching a list of businesses for

`natural cat food`

we can tell that `cat` is significantly more important to match on than `natural`, and would expect pet supply stores to come back.

But because `natural` is just as rare a word as `cat`, the Salon with "natural hair care products" is being returned with a similar score to the Pet Supply store that only has "cat" in their description.

If I switched to the "AND" operator, then nothing would be returned at all, though. So how do I get ES to figure out that `cat` is a more relevant word to match on than `natural` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boosting in that case. Have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html)

Comment: It looks like boosting is only for fields, not individual words

Comment: You can change their order in the query as individual words on same level are given equal priority as shown here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-scoring.html Or give me the exact query you are using so that i have a better idea of how I can help.

Comment: Further i think you are using query string, use bool query instead